# MySQL Error While Trying To Display A Table On a DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=dp;User Id=root;password=''");
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dp WHERE id LIKE " + txt_id.Text, con);
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StackTrace:" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

Problem is, It throws a MySQL exception,

> Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in
>   MySql.Data.dll
>       StackTrace:   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>          at Dispatching_Software.SearchUsers.btn_search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Dispatching Software\Dispatching
>   Software\SearchUsers.cs:line 34

What I'm trying to do is search for users within a table and display them, The problem seems to be `SDA.Fill(dt)`;

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` like that. Try using: `"SELECT * FROM dp WHERE id =" + txt_id.Text`

Comment: Thank you for you're response, I have now fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `con.Open();` when you are using `MySqlDataAdapter`. Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dp WHERE id LIKE '%' + @a + '%'", con);
SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txt_id.Text);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
 MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dp WHERE id LIKE @a", con);
SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@a", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = "%" + txt_id.Text;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have been looking into AntiMySQL injection, I believe this will help me alot with this project, Thanks.

Comment: You might add that in addition to _not_ using `con.Open()`, that the `MySqlConnection` instance should be wrapped in a `using` statement.